# Why I can't login without a password in my encrypted account?

Tags: login, security, encryption

I have an encrypted disk, and I get asked for a password before reaching the login prompt, then again to log in.

As I have only a single user account, the password to which is the same as my disk encryption password, the login prompt on startup offers no additional security, so I'd like to disable it and simply login automatically.

I attempted to follow [this guide](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/login-without-a-password-on-ubuntu/), but when I go to `User Accounts` I don't see the "Asked on Login" option, so this menu has presumably changed since 13.04.

How can I set up Ubuntu so that I only get asked for a login once?

Comment: Don't look in `User Accounts`. Maybe try in `Startup ans Sessions`, and check some `Automatically login without asking for password ... ` something checkbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The act of encrypting also implies you have to abide by the rules set for encrypting. One of those rules is: NO automatic login. Your password is required to unwrap the mount pass phrase used to decrypt your home.

If you want automatic login: remove the encryption.

> I don't see the "Asked on Login" option, so this menu has presumably changed since 13.04.

No, it is as intended: encryption does not allow automatic login.

---

> I have an encrypted disk, and I get asked for a password before reaching the login prompt, then again to log in.

Password is asked for every encrypted partition. Do you have both / and /home encrypted? If so have a look at [this how to](http://tristan.lt/blog/luks-password-twice/).

Comment: Thanks for this. In that case, maybe I asked the wrong question. It should have been; "How do users with an encrypted home directory avoid having to write the same password twice just to log in?". I want to keep the encryption, just not the redundant step to log in.

Comment: add it to the question please :-)

Comment: oh and do you have TWO encrypted disks perhaps?

Comment: I have updated the question. Regarding the two disks... Maybe! I'm not sure, but that would explain it. Looking at my partitions, it looks like my swap disk is encrypted... I think I need to do some digging. Thanks!

Comment: added a link to a 2 encrypted disk with 1 time asked password, But I bet you just need to re-unencrypt swap for this to be asked once.